# jQuery newbie: How do I externalize non-click functions in ajax content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

jQuery newbie here. I've got a page template where I'm using jQuery .load() to load my content into tabs. Problem is, functions weren't working unless I put them directly in the content pages (rather than in an external js file). I figured out how to make click events work by changing things like this:

```
$("a.icon-search").click(function () {
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click','a.icon-search',function() {
```

But how do I make functions work for non-click events? For example, lets say I'm loading "contact.html" into my index file, and that page has an accordion in it. If I put this in my external js file, it doesn't work:

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion();
```

I have to put it directly in "contact.html", which is pretty messy.

So my question is, is there an easy way to put functions like that in external files like there is with click events? I looked at the jQuery "on()" event handler documentation, but the only example it had other than click was submit.

Comment: is    $( ".accordion" ).accordion();   in $(document).ready?  also, are you doing the ajax load after the page has loaded via click or something?

Comment: I have a document.ready enclosing everything in my external js file. I've got a template with three divs that I'm loading header, content, and nav into. When you click a link in nav, it loads a new html file into the content div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place JavaScript in a certain file and execute it after loading content via Ajax, you can use a combination of the ajax load callback `$(<selector>).load(<url>,<callback>)` and JQuery's [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) function.

E.g.

```
$('#content').load(urlToLoad,runJSforAjaxContent);

function runJSforAjaxContent() {
        $.getScript("myAccordion.js");
}
```

If you want everything in a single JS file, then store the definitions in a callback function per tab in that file.

E.g.

```
$('#tab1').load(urlToLoad,runJSforTab1Content);
$('#tab2').load(urlToLoad,runJSforTab2Content);

function runJSforTab1Content() {
       // An accordion in tab1 ajax content
      $('.accordion').accordion();
}
function runJSforTab2Content() {
       // A rooltip in tab2 ajax content
      $('.tooltip').tooltip();
}
```

Comment: OK, but in order to use this method, I would have to have a seperate js file for each html page, correct? If so, it seems like that's not much better than putting embedded js into the html files.

Comment: Updated - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: The only hitch with this is that I'm loading my pages via the following: $(document).on( 'click', 'nav a', function(event) { $('.ui-tabs-panel:visible').load(this.href);}); With this method, I'll have to give every link an ID, and trigger the events by referencing them. Could something like the $("#book").load example on this page be used instead? [link](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)